# Ejb Home interface in netbeans

Tags: jsp, netbeans, ejb, ejb-3.0

I am new to EJB ,I am  using Netbean IDE.
I am able to create a session bean remote interface but not able to create Home interface, please help me ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're able to create remote interface, so I'm just curious why you are not able to create local interface.

It is as simple as it is, your local interface should look like this:

```
@Local
public interface MyLocalBean {
   void someMethod();
}
```

Annotated your interface with `@Local` annotation from `javax.ejb` package and here you go, you have local (home) interface.